# Convert a pandas dataset to numpy

Tags: pandas, numpy

I am trying to read my dataset and convert it to a numpy. I found this error how can I solve it. I tried to change the attribure of data but the same problem

```
def df_to_npy(df, left_context=5, right_context=5):
    print 'Converting DataFrame to Numpy...'
    cntlab = 0
    cntfeat = 0
    for idx, row in df.iterrows():
        cntlab += row['labs'].shape[0]
        cntfeat += row['feats'].shape[0]

    if cntfeat == cntlab:
        cnt = cntfeat
```

**AttributeError: 'float' object has no attribute 'shape'**

Comment: Would `df.to_records()` accomplish the same thing?  https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_records.html#pandas.DataFrame.to_records

Comment: row['label'] is a float in the loop, you was thinking about like a numpy

Comment: The problem in this line '''cntfeat += row['feats'].shape[0]'''

Comment: @DaveCosta when using 'df.to_records' it gives ValueError: too many values to unpack

Comment: Did you try [`to_numpy`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_numpy.html) ? If that does not do what you wish, you should probably add a bit more details and a reproducible example demonstrating what you try to achieve

Comment: you don't need a lopp for it, you could show your dataframe and your expected output, but try: `print(row['labs'])` in the loop before `cntlab += row['labs'].shape[0]` float object has not atrribute shape because it is not a numpy ....